# Call parent function from object attribute

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm building a GUI in Kivy. Part of the application needs to open up a pop up box containing a button, whose callback function calls a function in that pop up boxes parent. I'm having some trouble getting the callback to work properly.

I would ideally pass the classes in as parents like this:

```
class A():
    def foo(self):
        print(foo)


class B(A):
    def foo(self):
        super(B, self).foo()
myB = B()
myB.foo()
```

but I need to pass in the Kivy definitions in as part of the object definition (see code below).

Any advice is welcome and let me know if you need more details!

EDITED (more accurate example of what my code looks like, apologies for changing this)
My Code:

```
from B import B


class Application(App):
    pass


class A(TabbedPanel):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.B = B()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Application().run()
```

```
from C import C


class B(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.C = C()

    def test_function(self):
        print("Test Function Worked!")
```

```
class C(Popup):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def on_button_release(self):
        super(C, self).test_function()
```

Idea being that `on_button_release` in class C, would then run `test_function` in class B

Comment: You need an instance of `B` to call `test_function`. Where is that going to come from?

Answer (score 0):

If you are only refering to attributes of class B, you could use a `@classmethod` over the function. You will then be able to call the function by the class name. eg. `B.test_function()`.

Other than that, you could include `class B` into the `Application` class as an attribute or in the bultin method [on_start](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.app.html#profiling-with-on-start-and-on-stop).

Comment: I've found that setting up the function as a class method has worked, but only if i have all the classes defined in the same python file. Its not a huge problem, but mainly for keeping myself and workflow organised, i had all the separate classes in separate files which are then imported into their parent class. So in A, B is imported and in B, C is imported. I can't get the classmethod to work this way as i need to import B into C and i get an Import Error due to circular import, how could i get around that?

Comment: You should have an ```App``` class. That class should be the container holding your other classes together.